# What are the different kingdoms and mages in the Witcher TV series?

Tags: the-witcher

In ***The Witcher*** series of *Netflix* there have been mentioned many places like *Cintra*, *Sodden*, *Redania*, *Temeria*, etc. What are all the kingdoms mentioned in the series? Who were the mages assigned to each of these kingdoms?

Comment: This is rather broad and unclear what exactly you want to find out. Also I wouldn't consider mages to be assigned. For example Yennefer just happened to be born in capital of Aedirn.

Comment: Second question is Cross-posted on SF&F.

Comment: Question in SF&F has an answear to this.

Comment: This question is based for the Netflix series only while SF&F was for books

Comment: See also the Witcher wiki: https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Northern_Kingdoms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Advisors

- Yennefer of Vengerberg - **Aedirn**
- Triss Merigold - **Temeria**
- Mousesack - **Cintra** (Druid, not a mage of the Brotherhood)
- Fringilla Vigo - **Nilfgaard**
- ? - **Rivia**
- ? - **Creyden**
- ? - **Lyria**
- ? - **Brokilion**
- ? - **Arcsea**

#### Mages / Unknown region

- Tissaia De Vries
- Artorius Vigo
- Istredd
- Vanielle of Brugge
- Sabrina Glevissig
- Stregobore
- Irion
- Vilgefortz
- Coral
- Atlan Kerk
- Hemet

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224841/who-are-the-mages-of-different-kingdoms-of-the-witcher